# Graph separator which is balanced on a subset of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

**Here's what I know:**

Given a graph $G(V,E)$, a *separator* for that graph is a subset $S\subseteq V$ such that $V\setminus S$ can be partitioned into two blocks $A$ and $B$ which are disconnected in the induced subgraph $G[V\setminus S]$. When you remove $S$ and edges from $S$, you end up with a disconnected graph.

A separator is *balanced* if $|A|\le|B|\le k|A|$ ($k\ge 1$; closer to $1$ is stronger; $k=2$ is most common). It's often useful for the subgraphs that $S$ separates from each other to be similar in size, so we have a special word for that.

**Here's what I don't know:**

Is there any literature on separators that are balanced relative to a subset $T\subseteq V$, where we don't require $|A|\le|B|\le k|A|$, but rather $|A\cap T|\le|B\cap T|\le k|A\cap T|$? Here, the partition blocks don't have to be similar sizes, but the way that the partition splits $T$ has to be even. If we set $T=V$, we get back normal balancing.

Note that this isn't a separator for the induced subgraph $G[T]$, since $S$ still has to be a separator for $G$, but $S\cap T$ *is* a balanced separator for $G[T]$. I believe an alternative way to define this would be a separator $S$ of $G$ such that $S\cap T$ is a balanced separator of $G[T]$.

**More discussion:**

An example: Say we have a large barbell graph $G$ containing two equally-large, disjoint cliques $M$ and $N$ connected with only a single edge from $u\in V(M)$ to $v\in V(N)$. The set $S=\{u\}$ is a balanced separator of $G$, because removing it will make the two cliques (of similar size once $u$ is removed) disconnected. However, relative to the subset $T=V(M)$, there are no small balanced separators, because cliques don't have small balanced separators.

More broadly, I'm interested in graphs for which, for *every* subset of vertices, we can find a small separator which is balanced on that subset. Barbell graphs don't have this property, even though they have small balanced separators. I know that barbell graphs don't have *recursive* small balanced separators (which I've seen discussed in the literature), and I know that my property entails having recursive small balanced separators. I don't know if the converse entailment holds. This broader question feels like it relates to graphs with bad expansion properties, but I can't find anything relevant in that literature, either.

I'd appreciate any references or search terms that might help me! Thanks!